# Python Binary? to Text/String

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to parse a possibly binary file as text/strings in Python. I'm not positive of the file format, so I'm assuming it's binary. Basically, it is an exported key (*.reg) from MS `regedit`. If I open the key in `Notepad++` I can read it easily. However, if I try to iterate the lines in python (specifically iPython Notebook) it prints gobbledygook. Here's a sample:

```
InFile = open("F:\Uninstallkey.reg","r")

for line in InFile:
    print "%r" % (line)

InFile.close()
```

Output:

```
'\xff\xfeW\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00w\x00s\x00 \x00R\x00e\x00g\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00y\x00 \x00E\x00d\x00i\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00 \x00V\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00 \x005\x00.\x000\x000\x00\r\x00\n'
'\x00\r\x00\n'
'\x00[\x00H\x00K\x00E\x00Y\x00_\x00L\x00O\x00C\x00A\x00L\x00_\x00M\x00A\x00C\x00H\x00I\x00N\x00E\x00\\\x00S\x00O\x00F\x00T\x00W\x00A\x00R\x00E\x00\\\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00\\\x00W\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00w\x00s\x00\\\x00C\x00u\x00r\x00r\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00V\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00\\\x00U\x00n\x00i\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00]\x00\r\x00\n'
'\x00\r\x00\n'
```

In notepad++:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall]
```

Strangely, in iPython it prints properly:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall]
```

Long story short, how can I tell the file format and how can I convert the file so I can print/parse it as text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above the file is in utf-16.  Here's an easy way to open files with encoding:

```
import codecs
InFile = codecs.open(path_to_registry, encoding='utf-16')
```

Comment: For future reference, how did you determine the encoding?

Comment: @TechMedicNYC Google :-)

Answer (score 2):

The file appears to be a plain text file that is simply encoded in little-endian [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).  Instead of using the normal `open` function, open the file with [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) with an `encoding` argument of `"UTF-16LE"`.

Comment: Really? decoding as 16LE results in:`✊✊嬀䠀䬀䔀夀开䰀伀䌀䄀䰀开䴀䄀䌀䠀䤀一䔀尀匀伀䘀吀圀䄀刀䔀尀䴀椀挀爀漀猀漀昀琀尀圀椀渀搀漀眀猀尀䌀甀爀爀攀渀琀嘀攀爀猀椀漀渀尀唀渀椀渀猀琀愀氀氀崀ഀ਀ਧ`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I think you selected big-endian (UTF-16BE) instead of little-endian.

Comment: `>>> print(z.decode('utf-16LE'))
✊✊嬀䠀䬀䔀夀开䰀伀䌀䄀䰀开䴀䄀䌀䠀䤀一䔀尀匀伀䘀吀圀䄀刀䔀尀䴀椀挀爀漀猀漀昀琀尀圀椀渀搀漀眀猀尀䌀甀爀爀攀渀琀嘀攀爀猀椀漀渀尀唀渀椀渀猀琀愀氀氀崀ഀ਀ਧ'`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: You're decoding the third line of the OP's output.  Because the OP wasn't taking encoding into account, Python ended each line after each `\n` byte, causing a break in the middle of a UTF-16LE character.  Thus, the lines after the first begin with a NUL byte that actually belongs to the line before, and applying UTF-16LE decoding to these lines without discarding the leading NUL produces erroneous results.  Try decoding all but the last byte of the first line or decoding all but the first & last bytes of the third line.